# Slick Slider - Implement using php causes background-image bug

Tags: javascript, php, css, slider, slick.js

Good day all,

I have made a rather cute slick-slider.

It works a treat before I make it utilise PHP and host it on my site.

```js
 $(function() {
  //console.log( "ready!" );

  // SLIDER
   console.clear();

   var carousels = $('.funky-slider');
   var config = {
    dots: true,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 700,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    responsive: [
     {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
       slidesToShow: 2
      }
     },
     {
      breakpoint: 767,
      settings: {
       slidesToShow: 1
      }
     }
    ]
   };
   carousels.slick(config);

   carousels.on('breakpoint', function(slick) {
    carousels.slick('setPosition');
    // console.log(slick.currentTarget.slick);
    var count = slick.currentTarget.slick.slideCount;
    var show = slick.currentTarget.slick.options.slidesToShow;

    if (show >= count) {
     carousels.slick('unslick');
    }

   });

   carousels.on('destroy', function() {
    carousels.slick(config);
   });
  // END SLIDER
 });
```

```css
 /* FUNKY SLIDER */
  /* FUNCTIONAILTY */
      .funky-slider, .slick-track, .funky-slide {
        height: 400px;
      }
      .funky-slide {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
   .funky-slider .slick-slide {
    outline: none;
   }
   .funky-slider .slick-dots {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2rem;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
   }
    .funky-slider .slick-dots li {
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
     margin: 0 0.25rem;
    }
    .funky-slider .slick-dots button {
     display: block;
     width: 1rem;
     height: 1rem;
     padding: 0;
     border: 1px solid white;
     border-radius: 100%;
     background-color: #db3c36;
     color: transparent;
     -webkit-transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s; /* Safari */
     transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
     outline: none;
    }
     .funky-slider .slick-dots li.slick-active button {
      background-color: #241f21;
      width: 1.6rem;
      height: 1.6rem;
     }
  /* END FUNCTIONAILTY */
 /* FUNKY SLIDER */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css"/>

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="funky-slider-container">
 <div class="funky-slider">
  <div class="funky-slide" style="background-image: url('https://usercontent2.hubstatic.com/12593011_f520.jpg')">
   Hello!
  </div>
  <div class="funky-slide">
   Hello!
  </div>
  <div class="funky-slide">
   Hello!
  </div>
  <div class="funky-slide">
   Hello!
  </div>
  <div class="funky-slide">
   Hello!
  </div>
  <div class="funky-slide">
   Hello!
  </div>
  <div class="funky-slide">
   Hello!
  </div>
  <div class="funky-slide">
   Hello!
  </div>
  <div class="funky-slide">
   Hello!
  </div>
  <div class="funky-slide">
   Hello!
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- END HTML -->

<!-- PHP SLIDER
 <?php
  $funky_slider = get_field('funky_slider');
 ?>
   <?php if( $funky_slider ) : ?>
  <section id="funky-slider" class="funky-slider-section">
   <div class="funky-slider">

    <?php while( have_rows('funky_slider') ): the_row();
     $funky_slider_image = get_sub_field('funky_slider_image');
    ?>

     <div class="funky-slide" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $funky_slider_image['url'] ?>')"></div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
   </div>
  </section>
 <?php endif; ?>
 -->
<!-- END PHP SLIDER -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

The example is only showing my HTML, JS, CSS version with my PHP version commented out.

I have then gone on to use ACF - Advanced Custom Fields within Wordpress and made the appropriate fields to generate an image url.

I then as illustrated in my commented out php code - set the background image.

The page will then load the slider beautifully when in full screen (larger than the first breakpoint - 1024px). However, will remove the inline-styles for the background-image when the page is made smaller than the first breakpoint.

Is this because slick slider removes inline styles?

Worst case scenario - you all get a beautiful slick slider starter kit...

Thanks, Jason.

Comment: Anybody? Ideas? :c

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what is happening. When entering the responsive slick settings it removes inline-styles.

To work around this I have used this code:

```
<!-- SLIDER -->
<?php
    $funky_slider = get_field('funky_slider');
?>
<?php if( $funky_slider ) : ?>

    <!-- generate image css -->
    <style>
        <?php
            $count = 1;
            while( have_rows('funky_slider') ): the_row();
            $funky_slider_image = get_sub_field('funky_slider_image');
        ?>

            .slick-slide:nth-of-type(<?php echo $count ?>) .funky-slide {
                background-image: url('<?php echo $funky_slider_image['url'] ?>');
            }

            <?php $count++; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </style>
    <!-- END generate image css -->

    <!-- generate slider -->
    <section id="funky-slider" class="funky-slider-section">
        <div class="funky-slider">
            <?php
                while( have_rows('funky_slider') ): the_row();
            ?>

                <div class="funky-slide">
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- END generate slider -->
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- END SLIDER -->
```

This creates a style sheet that applies the background image to the relevant slide. Then goes on to create the slides that will be slicked.

Hope I have helped a few people in my situation.

Thanks, Jason.